# How to find one solution of a linear inequality with constrains quickly?

Tags: inequality, algorithms

Here is the inequality: $a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}+\dots+a_{n}x_{n} \leq B$. 
Assume we know the values of $\{a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{n}\}$ ($a_{i} > 0, \forall i \in [1,n]$)and $B$, is there any algorithm that can be used to quickly find a solution of $\{x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n}\}$, given that $x_i$ is an integer and $x_{i} \geq 0 $ ($\forall i \in [1,n]$)? I want the solution to make $a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}+\dots+a_{n}x_{n}$ approximate $B$ as closely as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question as posed, choose $i$ so that $a_i$ is smallest. If $B<0$, there is no solution unless $a_i<0$, in which case take $x_i>B/a_i$, and the rest zero. If $B>0$, set $x_i=1$, and the rest zero. If there is a solution, this will find it.

Comment: I missed a constrain. I want the value of $a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}+\dots+a_{n}x_{n}$ to approximate $B$ as closely as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can find a solution quickly. Of course if you remove the constraints on $x_i'$s, then using Euclidean algorithm you can find a solution in polynomial time. One possible approach is using LLL, but is  not guaranteed that it will give you a solution. But in case it works you'll get one fast. Of course you have to consider a suitable lattice. There is some bibliography for lattice based methods that you can check (for instance see [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-69346-7_18)). This problem is NP-hard in general.

Comment: I'm confused about setting $a_i=1$, why is it necessary?

Comment: Setting $a_i = 1$ is not correct. To get an instance that is equivalent to the subset sum problem for set $S$ you would need to set the $a_i$ to the values of the set $S$. You would additionally need $x_i \leq 1$ since otherwise you could choose the same number twice.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I deleted.